# Nhibernate query with null child

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I need to retrieve all the users with a valid `Wish` property (so not null). This is the xml of my class:

```
<class name="Project.Engine.Domain.User,Project.Engine" table="Users" lazy="true">
  <id name="UserID" column="UserID">
    <generator class="native" />
  </id>
  <property name="Firstname" column="Firstname" type="string" not-null="true"
    length="255" />
  <property name="Lastname" column="Lastname" type="string" not-null="true"
    length="255" />
  <property name="Email" column="Email" type="string" not-null="true"
    length="255" />
  <one-to-one name="Wish" cascade="all" property-ref="UserID"
    class="Project.Engine.Domain.Wish, Project.Engine"  />
</class>
```

The method to get all my users is the following:

```
public PagedList<User> GetAll(int pageIndex, int pageSize,
    string orderBy, string orderByAscOrDesc)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        var users = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User));
        users.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("Wish"));
        return users.PagedList<User>(session, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

As you can notice, I have added the Restriction on the child object. This doesn't work properly as the method return all users including the ones with `Wish` property as null. Any help?

this is the xml for child:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Project.Engine.Domain.Wish,Project.Engine" table="Wish" lazy="false">
    <id name="WishID" column="WishID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="UserID" column="UserID" type="int" not-null="true" length="32" />
    <property name="ContentText" column="ContentText" type="string" not-null="false" length="500" />
    <property name="Views" column="Views" type="int" not-null="true" length="32" />
    <property name="DateEntry" column="DateEntry" type="datetime" not-null="true" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: You should include `Wish` mapping too.

Comment: I have updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a bug with `one-to-one` and `null` testing of the side which may not exist. I had already encountered it but forgot about it. The `property-ref` just render it a bit more tricky to diagnose, but it does exist on actual `one-to-one` too.

Here is its corresponding [issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3117) in NHibernate tracking tool.

Workaround: test for `null` state of an non-nullable property of `Wish`, like `Wish.Views`.

Forgive the wild guess on test syntax, I do not use [nhibernate-criteria](/questions/tagged/nhibernate-criteria) anymore since years, but try by example:

```
public PagedList<User> GetAll(int pageIndex, int pageSize,
    string orderBy, string orderByAscOrDesc)
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {
        var users = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(User));
        users.Add(Restrictions.IsNotNull("Wish.Views"));
        return users.PagedList<User>(session, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

Using [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate), I confirm this workaround works with my own projects, which gives by example:

```
// The "TotalAmount != null" seems to never be able to come false from a 
// .Net run-time view, but converted to SQL, yes it can, if TransactionRecord
// does not exist.
// Beware, we may try "o.TransactionsRecord != null", but you would get struck
// by https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3117 bug.
return q.Where(o => o.TransactionsRecord.TotalAmount != null);
```

I maintain my other answer since you may consider using a `many-to-one` instead, especially since you do not have made a bidirectionnal mapping (no corresponding `constrained` `one-to-one` in `Wish`) in addition to not having an actual `one-to-one`. `many-to-one` does not suffer of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

`one-to-one` mapping using `property-ref` is not an "actual" one-to-one, and usually this is a sign a `many-to-one` mapping should be used instead.
Maybe this is not related to your trouble, but you may give it a try.

An "actual" one-to-one has the dependent table primary key equals to the parent table primary key. (Dependent table, `Wish` in your case, would have a foreign primary key, `UserId` in your case. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802172/1178314).)

<sup>I have sometime "played" with 'one-to-one property-ref', and I always ended giving it up due to many issues. I replaced that with more classical mappings, either changing my db for having an actual one-to-one, or using a many-to-one and living with a collection on child side though it would always contain a single element.</sup>